# Extracting characters after a particular text

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am extracting a page from website using cURL command.

```
curl "www.google.com" -s |  w3m -dump -T text/html > foo.txt
```

The w3m command outputs the HTML page in a much more simpler format so that the string manipulation in the `foo.txt` is simpler now.

Now, I have some values in my `foo.txt` which get extracted as below.

```
Assistant director at Hollywood studios
Student at University of Texas at Arlington
```

Now, I need to extract only the values after **at** to store in my database. How can I do it? For example, for the above input, I need the values as,

```
Hollywood Studios
University of Texas at Arlington
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to pipe your text into grep and cut:

```
grep -o ' at .*$' foo.txt | cut -c5-
```

This will extract the longest string for each line which starts with ' at '. The cut will then trim the leading ' at '.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to replace the first occurrence of `at` with a tab, so now you have a tab delimited file and you can use `awk` properly:

```
$ sed 's/ at /\t/' foo.txt | awk -F'\t' '{print $1" :: "$2}'
Assistant director :: Hollywood studios
Student :: University of Texas at Arlington
```

Or, the same thing in Perl:

```
$ perl -ne '/(.+?) at (.+)/; print "$1 :: $2\n"' foo.txt
```

or even

```
$ perl -F'\sat\s' -lane 'print "$F[0] :: @F[1..$#F]"' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `at` as column separator in `awk`. The following should work:

```
awk -F'at' '{print $2}' foo.txt
```

Comment: Some words will include those letters together... Also, you'd need $3 in the case of Texas `at` Arlington.

Comment: aha gotcha! let me think.