# Extract text from source code website

Tags: html

I need extract text with a bash script from a website in HTML, I used [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114639/extracting-characters-after-a-particular-text) but doesn't work fine for me, because I must edit and format the output text. I need the text between the tag:

```
<p><p tabindex="0">
```

Example I am surf in `https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clementine/`
In Firefox displayed the next tag in your source code:

```
<p><p tabindex="0">Clementine is a multiplatform music player focusing on a fast and easy-to-use interface for searching and playing your music.</p><p tabindex="0">Summary of included features :</p><ul><li>Search and play your local music library.</li><li>Listen to internet radio from Last.fm, SomaFM and Magnatune.</li><li>Tabbed playlists, import and export M3U, XSPF, PLS and ASX.</li><li>Visualisations from projectM.</li><li>Transcode music into MP3, Ogg Vorbis, Ogg Speex, FLAC or AAC</li><li>Edit tags on MP3 and OGG files, organise your music.</li><li>Download missing album cover art from Last.fm.</li><li>Native desktop notifications using libnotify.</li><li>Supports MPRIS, or remote control using the command-line.</li><li>Remote control using a Wii Remote, MPRIS or the command-line.</li><li>Copy music to your iPod, iPhone, MTP or mass-storage USB player.</li><li>Queue manager. It is largely a port of Amarok 1.4, with some features rewritten to take advantage of Qt4.</li></ul></p>
```

How to extract the above text, after `<p><p tabindex="0">` ? remember is only a example, the website and tag could change.

> Output='Clementine is a multiplatform music player focusing on a fast
>   and easy-to-use interface for searching and playing your music.'

---

thanks to $John1024 your solution work fine  with ubuntu site, but with opensuse doesn't display correctly. this is the variable with OpenSuse site:

`output="$(wget -q http://software.opensuse.org/package/clementine -O - | sed -n 's/.*<p id="pkg-desc">\([^<]*\).*/\1/p')"`.

echo $output

`Clementine is a modern music player and library organiser. Clementine is a` (doesn't display completaly the text)

I tried also:

`output="$(wget -q http://software.opensuse.org/package/clementine/ -O - | sed -ne '/<p id="pkg-desc">/, /[.</p>]$/p')"`

echo $output

`<p id="pkg-desc">Clementine is a modern music player and library organiser. Clementine is a port of Amarok 1.4, with some features rewritten to take advantage of Qt4.` `(it displays with '<p id="pkg-desc">')`

Comment: do you only need the first occurance? Or do you need all occurances of text between those tags? how should they be diferenciated?

Comment: So how do we know when to stop? Do you want the entire line?

Comment: thanks @terdon only the first information from <p><p tabindex="0"> to </p><p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, one should use a tool that understands html.  For limited purposes, though, a simple command may suffice.  In this case, `sed` is sufficient to do what you ask and works well in `bash` scripts.  If you have captured the source html into `index.html`, then:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*<p><p tabindex="0">\([^<]*\).*/\1/p' index.html 
Clementine is a multiplatform music player focusing on a fast and easy-to-use interface for searching and playing your music.
```

Or, to capture the html and process it all in one step:

```
$ wget -q https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clementine/ -O - | sed -n 's/.*<p><p tabindex="0">\([^<]*\).*/\1/p' 
Clementine is a multiplatform music player focusing on a fast and easy-to-use interface for searching and playing your music.
```

To capture that output to a `bash` variable:

```
output="$(wget -q https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clementine/ -O - | sed -n 's/.*<p><p tabindex="0">\([^<]*\).*/\1/p')"
```

The `-n` option is used on `sed`.  This tells it not to print output unless we explicitly ask.  `sed` goes through the input line by line looking for a line which matches `.*<p><p tabindex="0">\([^<]*\).*`.  All the text that follows the `<p tabindex="0">` and the next tag is captured in variable 1.  Everything on that line is then replaced with just that captured text which is then printed.

Comment: Hi, work fine with ubuntu site, but with opensuse doesn't display correctly. this is the variable with OpenSuse site: output="$(wget -q http://software.opensuse.org/package/clementine -O - | sed -n 's/.*<p id="pkg-desc">\([^<]*\).*/\1/p')". I tried also: output="$(wget -q http://software.opensuse.org/package/clementine/ -O - | sed -ne '/<p id="pkg-desc">/, /[.</p>]$/p')"